# ExtJs 5.1 - Ext.Panel with XML-Highlighting, editing, linenumbering capabilities

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, codemirror

Basically I am i need of an [Ext.Panel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel) which contains an **XML-Editor** together with *syntax-highlighting*, *line numbers* and *editing*.

I have searched through the web and found the **Javascript API** [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/index.html).

I have implemented something, but the alignment of the CodeMirror-object-Textfield **does not adjust** itself to the **Top/left** of the Ext.Panel and also no line-numbers are seen:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- ext imports -->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/ext-5.1.1/build/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ext-5.1.1/build/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/resources/ext-theme-neptune-all.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ext-5.1.1/build/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/ext-theme-neptune.js"></script>

    <!-- codemirror imports -->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/CodeMirror-master/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CodeMirror-master/lib/codemirror.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/CodeMirror-master/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>

    <script type ="text/javascript">
        Ext.onReady(function(){
            var panel_1 = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                    frame:true,
                    id: 'panel_1_id',
                    title: 'panel_1',
                    padding: '10 10 10 10',
                    margin: '10 10 10 10',
                    autoScroll: true
                });

            var vp = new Ext.Viewport({
                layout: 'fit',
                items: [panel_1],
                autoScroll: true,
                renderTo : Ext.getBody()
            });

            var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror(panel_1.body, {
              value: "<XXX><YYY><AAA>foo1</AAA></YYY><ZZZ>foo2</ZZZ></XXX>"
            });
        });
      </script>
    </head>
     <body>
     </body>
</html>
```

---

### So the following questions arise:

**1.) I thought about [extending Ext.Component](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/core_concepts/components.html) and somehow pack the CodeMirror object inside it?**
Is this possible?
**2.) Is it possible to adapt my little codeexample from above to align it correctly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved with a few slight tweaks to your code.

The key point here is that the behaviour of **CodeMirror** will vary depending on the type of the first parameter you pass to the **CodeMirror** constructor. Passing a *HTML element* (as in your example) will result in the HTML DOM function **appendChild()** being called. And this is why there is a large space before your new element, because it is being appended after the body of the panel.

If you pass in a function (acting as a callback) to the **CodeMirror** constructor then you will be returned with the *HTML element* that is the **CodeMirror**. Constructing the element this way enables you to replace the body element of the panel with the new HTML element (rather than appending).

This can be achieved by creating a simple function. The code changes you require are as follows....

**Create a function to pass to CodeMirror constructor**

```
var codeMirrorCallbackFunction = function(codeMirrorEl) { 
    var panelDom = panel_1.el.dom;        
    // the node at index 1 is the body (index 0 is panel header)
    panelDom.replaceChild(codeMirrorEl, panelDom.childNodes[1]);
};
```

**Create the CodeMirror object passing the function as 1st parameter**

```
var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror(codeMirrorCallbackFunction, {
    value: "<XXX><YYY><AAA>foo1</AAA></YYY><ZZZ>foo2</ZZZ></XXX>"
});
```

**Update the padding of the Panel**

```
// without this change the panel header and codemirror html overlap
padding: '25 10 10 10'
```

Comment: This works, there are some minor issues now: resizing does not work without problem and the scrollbar is also bugged when resizing.

Comment: I added a resize-event to the panel_1 and do a `code_mirror.setSize(panel_1.lastbox.width-30, panel_1.lastbox.height-60)` in the resize-event-handler-method. Now the CodeMirror-object perfectly fits the panel even after resize and entering long texts. Thanks for your help John Tough.

Comment: Excellent! That sounds great.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing good, you only need to add a property like

```
var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror(panel.body, {
                           value: "<XXX><YYY><AAA>foo1</AAA></YYY><ZZZ>foo2</ZZZ></XXX>",
                           lineNumbers: true
                        });
```